Talking dogs movie
The movie is with a bunch of talking dogs. A big white pit bull is looking for his owners. In the end he finds them and has a girlfriend white dog.
It's most likely an american movie made after 2000 and it's not an animation.

Talking white dog looking for his owners sounds like Homeward Bound: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107131/

Any more details that may help identification? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Animation or life action?

@mikeTheLiar, Hi Mike, please post your answer as an answer so it can eventually be marked correct...

@mikeTheLiar It's not Homeward Bound.

I hope you're misremembering the movie Baxter because that would be fun.

@MeatTrademark It's not Baxter.

Yeah, a guy can dream though...

@mikeTheLiar Thanks to you, I found the answer.

@JohnSmith the only reason I didn't post as an answer is that I don't think Chance is a pit bull.

It's Homeward Bound 2: Lost in San Francisco.

So it's not Homeward Bound, it's Homeward Bound 2? I try not to use this idiom, but... lol.
